# register multiple parameters to an individual using DEAP

Tags: python, deap

I have to integrate DEAP into a bigger frame work.

For testing I defined:

```
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
from collections import *
import random

NAME = 0
TYPE = 1
INITIAL = 2
MIN = 3
MAX = 4
CATEGORY = 5

IND_SIZE = 1

Data = OrderedDict()
Data['P1'] = ['distance' , float, 8.     ,7.9    ,8.1  , [] ]
Data['P2'] = ['velocity' , float, 80.    ,79.7   ,83.3 , [] ]
Data['P3'] = ['rigid'    , int  , 0      ,0      ,1    , ['false','true'] ]

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

for Key in Data:
    if Data[Key][TYPE] is float:
        toolbox.register(Data[Key][NAME], random.uniform, Data[Key][MIN], Data[Key][MAX])
    if Data[Key][TYPE] is int:
        toolbox.register(Data[Key][NAME], random.randint, Data[Key][MIN], Data[Key][MAX])

AttrSet = (toolbox.distance, toolbox.velocity,  toolbox.rigid)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initCycle, creator.individual, AttrSet, IND_SIZE)
```

This runs as expected, but if the framework delivers Data with different `len()` `AttrSet` has to be changed, too

Is there a way to create `AttrSet` from Data, e.g. in the loop where the parameters are registered?

`toolbox.register()` always returns None, so this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Python built-in function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), which lets you get attributes of an object by name.

As explained in the docs: `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`.

So you could do something like:

```py
toolbox = base.Toolbox()

AttrSet = []

for Key in Data:
    if Data[Key][TYPE] is float:
        toolbox.register(Data[Key][NAME], random.uniform, Data[Key][MIN], Data[Key][MAX])
    elif Data[Key][TYPE] is int:
        toolbox.register(Data[Key][NAME], random.randint, Data[Key][MIN], Data[Key][MAX])

    AttrSet.append(getattr(toolbox, Data[Key][NAME]))

toolbox.register("individual", tools.initCycle, creator.individual, AttrSet, IND_SIZE)
```

Comment: Works fine, but I have to do ist using a list, otherwise the order of the parameters is lost.

Comment: I update it in case it might be helpful for others.